# How do I change a URL link in CSS into a local image that I downloaded in my pc

Tags: css

How do I change a URL link in CSS into a local image that I downloaded in my pc.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
    115deg,
    rgba(0, 2, 1, 0.507),
    rgba(8, 185, 126, 0.562)**strong text**
  ),
  url(https://cutewallpaper.org/21/vaporwave-steam-backgrounds/Vaporwave-Wallpapers-Top-Free-Vaporwave-Backgrounds-.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder called assets in your project and paste the image inside that. Provide the relative path in `background-image: url('../assets/images/yourimage.png')` (an example)